# Monitor Changes to a Database and Update List

Tags: c#, angularjs, node.js, wpf, web-services

I'm developing a web app to deal with video editing jobs. It has 3 different interfaces:a web browser interface, a mobile app and a desktop app, and they all consume the same web service. The desktop interface is a widget-like app and its only function is to list unfinished jobs. It's implemented in C#/WPF, and it already lists jobs I want, by doing a GET Http Request to my Web Service. However, if a new job is added or removed from the list (by deletion or because it was finished), the Desktop should update automatically, but it currently isn't doing so.Other than resending the GET request periodically and updating, is there a way that I can send the information from my web application to the application, each time a change occurs, so that the app will reflect those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) for this solution?

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for, Thank you.